# How to get contact list using campaign ID - Mailchimp API

Tags: api, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

How to get contact list using campaign ID - Mailchimp API  - i have a webhook trigger on campaign sending, the webhook returns only the below json,

```js
body{"type":"campaign","fired_at":"2020-02-24 07:21:16","data":{"id":"***","subject":"Thanks for joining us","status":"sent","reason":"","list_id":"*****"}}
```

So the campaign ID is there, so is there any way to get the contact list of the campaign sent.

Thank you!

Comment: Just found out - to get the list related to the campaign the mail chimp account should be and subscribed one. I upgraded my free account to a subscribed and now i do get the list from the response itself

Answer (score 0):

Just found out - to get the list related to the campaign the mail chimp account should be and subscribed one. I upgraded my free account to a subscribed and now i do get the list from the response itself.

Thank you!